# What is a database with ".res" in its name?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm not that experienced with MySQL and I'm trying to fix some databases.

In mysql, a "SHOW DATABASES" shows (among others) the main database **"MainDB"** and another database **"MainDB.res"**. If I'm trying to DUMP or USE that second database (with ``` `` ``` around the name), I get the error
`ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'MainDB.res'`.
Dumping the MainDB works without problems. Now I'm wondering if MainDB.res is some special or maybe auto-generated database that the MySQL admin has no rights for? How can I look into that database?

---

Detailed information:
Originally I wanted to see all ibfk connections between all tables.
Now I'm searching for a bug in the databases because I can't look into information_schema, as a
`mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE;`
results in the error message
`ERROR 1103 (42000): Incorrect table name 'accessgroup'`
and I read some forum posts suggesting that the error happens because more than one table was found with that name, and renaming it may solve the problem. That is the reason I wanted to take a look at "MainDB.res" in the first place...

**EDIT:**

MainDB.res/ is indeed a direcory (in /var/lib/mysql/) containing some, but not all files in the directory MainDB/. Some missing files are of type .frm, some of .MYD and .MYI. 'accessgroup.frm' is in both directories. (I can't anonymize the output of ls -l enough to paste it here.) I'll try what happens if I move the directoy MainDB.res somewhere else.

Comment: Please paste the output of ls -la /location_to_datadir/MainDB.res/...In my opinioun it is not the actual database

Comment: Can't paste that here, but added a description of the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by miracle173 pointed me in the right direction:

The database 'MainDB.res' probably was a backup of 'MainDB' by copying the directory. That way, the copy was seen by MySQL as another database and this invalidated the entries in 'information_schema', as were the databases 'MainDBOld', 'MainDBTest' and 'mysql.old'...

After I moved 'MainDB.res' out of the MySQL directory, the ERROR 1103 changed to `ERROR 1103 (42000): Incorrect table name 'columns_priv'` (the table name changed).

After moving all "duplicates" (always stopping mysqld), the query `SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;` worked immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The MainDB.res is not the Actual database.Someone by mistake have created it in your data directory.

Have a look at the content of my datadir

```
-rwx------ 1 mysql mysql     0 2012-05-23 14:48 debian-5.1.flag
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql  4096 2012-05-28 16:09 mysql
-rwx------ 1 mysql mysql     6 2012-05-23 14:49 mysql_upgrade_info
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql     5 2012-05-29 09:15 OSS-240.pid
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 36864 2012-05-28 16:58 test
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql  4096 2012-05-29 10:39 world
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql   4096 2012-05-29 14:29 world.res
```

where world.res is the directory which i have created as

```
mkdir world.res
```

and now when i want to acess it in the MySQL Shell see the result(The world.res is created as #mysql50#world.res by itself.
)

```
mysql> use #mysql50#world.res
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name '#mysql50#world.res'
```

So in my opinion the MainDB.res is not the database.

**UPDATE**

In MySQL you can't create the Database's that contains the word "."

```
mysql> create database test.res;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.res' at line 1
```

so it is sure that that was not your database.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't even work with ` backticks `.

Comment: ok..cheers..!!!

Answer (score 1):

if think if a database "MainDB.res" is shown then there exists a directory "MainDB.res" in the mysql directory. Perhaps you have created this directory with operation system tools. What is the content of the "MainDB.res" directory?

Comment: See my edit. I'll try stopping mysql and moving that directory somewhere else...

Comment: Indeed the original owner of this database must have created that directory by copying (probably as a backup). I was able to resolve my problem, so I posted the answer *for future reference*. :)